# React array state is being returned as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, axios

I am using a MUI Autocomplete field that takes an array for options.
I created this hook that takes the input value and fetches the API based on it.
This is the code for it:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function useFetchGames(searchString) {
  const [gameSearch, setGameSearch] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchString) setGameSearch(fetchData(searchString));
  }, [searchString]);

  return gameSearch;
}

const generateSearchOptions = (array) => {
  const tempArray = [];
  array.map((item) => {
    tempArray.push(item.name);
  });
  return tempArray;
};

async function fetchData(searchString) {
  const res = await axios
    .post("/api/games", { input: searchString })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  return generateSearchOptions(res.data);
}
```

And then i am calling this hook in the component where i have the autocomplete element.

```
const searchOptions = useFetchGames(inputValue);
```

The issue is,`useFetchGames` is supposed to return an array since the state is an array. But whenever the input changes, i get an error that you cant filter or map an object. Basically Autocompolete element is trying to map `searchOptions` but it is not an array.
I even tried to log its type with `log(typeof searchOptions);` and it returns an object.
I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Edit: Here is the log of `res.data`. it is an array of objects. That is why i am remapping it to an array of just the names.
[image]

Comment: console the result of the res.data

Comment: It is an array of objects. The code used to work fine when it was implemented in the component itself. But i needed to reuse it in other components, so I decided to make it into a hook. I will add the log of res.data in the edit

Comment: also the function `fetchData(searchString)` would return a promise instead of data you expected it to be ...

Comment: res.data is an array. About the promise, how can i work around it. I tried to follow what they did in the docs of creaeting customHooks in the react website.

Comment: sorry my bad it was an assumption and edited seeing your edit :)

Comment: if you console the `fetchData(searchString)` do you get the result?

Comment: You might be getting a promise when you call fetchData function. Maybe try calling that with await keyword.

Comment: @arp true that but await cannot be called inside a regular function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the promise back when you invoked `fetchData(searchString)` as it is an `async` function which always return a `promise` back

I would do it as

```
useEffect(() => {
  // wrapping it as a async function so we can await the data (promise) returned from another async function
  async function getData() {
    const data = await fetchData(searchString);
    setGameSearch(data);
  }
  if (searchString) {
    getData();
  }
}, [searchString]);
```

also refactoring this `generateSearchOptions` function in order to remove the creation of `temp` array which I feel is not required when using a `map` - below as

```
const generateSearchOptions = (array) => array.map(item => item.name)
```

Comment: I tried this. But I am logging ```gameSearch``` which is the state and it keeps logging a promise.

Comment: did you try logging `data` inside the effect ? also where did you log `gameSearch` can you please tell ?

Comment: nevermind, i did not copy your solution correctly. What you suggester worked. I marked it as an answer. Thank you so much. Wrapping it in an async function worked.